# Define también la propiedad estándar "appearance" por compatibilidad css(vendorPrefix) Estoy trabajando en Chrome

Tags: python, css, bootstrap

Al momento de levantar la app web en el servidor en Vs Code tengo estos errores no sé como solucionarlo[image: Define también la propiedad estándar "appearance" por compatibilidad css(vendorPrefix)]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.